# Alguien más ve los motivos de cierre en inglés?

Tags: bug

Están saliendo los motivos de cierre en inglés

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Incluso cuando sugieren duplicados para cerrar esta pregunta xD

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sí, revisando me aparece lo mismo, también cuando das clic en `cerrar` así como en `reportar`

Comment: @Phi estuve revisando y al momento de reportar una respuesta que en realidad no lo es si me aparece todo el menú en español, caso contrario cuando quiero votar para cerrar alguna pregunta si que me sale en inglés

Comment: CONFIRMADO!!! :(

Comment: y ya esta todo traducido en traucir...

Comment: Me suena a que cambiaron los textos porque ahora son todos amables, pero no coincide con lo que estaba traducido antes. Miren en SO en inglés y verán que ahora los motivos de cierre son todos _sofisticados_

Comment: Si, me pasó ayer. Pero parece que ya quedó corregido.

Comment: [Esta es la explicación de qué pasó con esos textos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4468/11272)

Comment: @g3rv4 me parece terrible que te respondan a ti hoy y no a mí desde la semana pasada xD

Comment: PD. El mensaje en fondo verde que salió cuando voté que sí respondía mi pregunta, también salió en inglés :)

Comment: Bueno es que precisamente fue @g3rv4 quien se contestó a sí mismo :P

Comment: Por favor, g3rv4, dile a @g3rv4 que no duplique preguntas! :P

Comment: Preferí hacer una pregunta canónica a la que podamos referenciar todas las veces que pase esto (que ya han sido unas cuantas). Esta pregunta habla sobre los motivos de cierre, por eso me pareció mejor no responder acá.

Comment: @g3rv4 Lo sé y por eso acepté la sugerencia de cerrar como duplicado :) Está mejor así