# ¿Alguien más ve la página de *Navegadores Soportados* en inglés?

Tags: discusión, traducciones, centro-de-ayuda

Haciendo la moderación cotidiana hoy, al intentar enlazar una de las páginas del centro de ayuda en un comentario, me di cuenta que el título de la página [*Navegadores Soportados*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/browser-support) de la sección [*Nuestro Modelo*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange) en el [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help), aparece en inglés:

[image: Sección Nuestro Modelo]

---

Siendo curioso por naturaleza, entré en dicha página y resulta que todo el contenido está en inglés:

[image: Página de Navegadores Soportados]

---

Entiendo que este es el sitio correcto para reportar estas cosas. Y es una buena oportunidad para realizar mi primera (y espero que no mi única) pregunta en Meta.

Comment: Lleva algunos días así, ya se lo había [informado](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52313841#52313841) a nuestro empleado-colaborador, al ser un texto corto no creo que haya que realizar otro proceso, solo el de informar, esperemos que esta publicación atraiga la atención de la traducción.

Comment: Ok, gracias. Eso indica que en algún momento lo arreglarán.

Comment: La página es estática, luego simplemente debe traducirse

Comment: Ok, pensé que se había roto o algo. Es que no sé si antes estaba en castellano. Igual hay gente que se encarga de eso, cierto?. O nosotros como usuarios podemos hacer también de traductores?. Esa parte no la veo clara aún. Sé que existe el sitio de traducir, pero entré una sola vez y la verdad no entendí mucho.

Comment: Creo que también pasó con los "Motivos de cierre": [Alguien más ve los motivos de cierre en inglés?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4464/alguien-m%c3%a1s-ve-los-motivos-de-cierre-en-ingl%c3%a9s)

Comment: hola! Escribí [una respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4467/11272) explicando el proceso actual para hacer traducciones en el centro de ayuda. Nunca confíen en los pings en el chat :)

Comment: Vale lo suyo sería cambiar el duplicado a esa otra!