# ¿Por qué aparece <X> en inglés? ¿Estamos perdiendo traducciones?

Tags: soporte, traducciones

Ayer, <X> estaba en español. Hoy entro al sitio y aparece en inglés.

¿Hay un bug con el sistema de traducciones? ¿Estamos perdiendo cosas que ya estaban traducidas?

Comment: Actualicé lo indicado en [¿Quieres ayudar a traducir las cadenas del sitio? Este es el proceso](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3166/83) para explicitar el uso de traducir.win.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

El código que traduce el sitio puede pensarse como un gran diccionario, donde para cada cadena en inglés tiene la correspondiente cadena en español.

Por lo que en algún lugar, existe algo del estilo:

```cs
var traducciones = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
  ["Hello"] = "Hola",
  ["Bye"] = "Chau"
}
```

Este diccionario se construye automáticamente analizando el código de Stack Overflow (para extraer las claves) y una base de datos (que viene de Transifex, que es populada por Traducir.win) que se usa para los valores.

Si alguien cambia el código para que en vez de decir "Hello" diga "Good morning", entonces, el sistema no encuentra cómo traducir "Good morning" a español.

En ese caso, donde antes decía "Hola", ahora dice "Good morning". Lo que hace falta para corregirlo es:

1. Ir a [traducir.win](https://traducir.win/)
2. Buscar ["Good morning"](https://traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Good%20morning)
3. Proponer una traducción.
4. Un reviewer tiene que aprobarla.
5. Un dev tiene que hacer un build de toda la red de Stack Exchange.

¡Y listo! (¡Ja!)

> Ahora... Esto también pasa si un dev cambia "Hello" por "hello", ya que el diccionario es case sensitive.