# Marqué una pregunta para cierre y el texto se puso en inglés, ¿por qué pasó esto? ¿hay algún bug en el sistema?

Tags: bug

Ayer marqué [una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/314932/29967) para cierre y el texto se puso en inglés, como pueden apreciar en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Esto se debe a algún bug en el sistema? ¿A alguien le ha pasado algo parecido?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [¿Por qué aparece <X> en inglés? ¿Estamos perdiendo traducciones?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4468/por-qu%c3%a9-aparece-x-en-ingl%c3%a9s-estamos-perdiendo-traducciones)

Comment: Sospecho que este cambio en concreto proviene de los nuevos mensajes que se han incorporado al sitio recientemente (como por ejemplo, cuando una pregunta está cerrada). Antes el mensaje decía algo como "Posible duplicado de", ya ahora se ha cambiado por ese "Responde esto a tu pregunta?". He encontrado las cadenas en traducir.win y las he traducido, en breve deberían verse ya correctamente

Comment: Relacionado: [New Post Notices rollout on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337013/346768)

Comment: @Pikoh la cadena que no encuentro es la que dice _Visible por el autor del post y usuarios con el privilegio de votos para cerrar/reabrir_. Estaría bien poner _publicación_ en lugar de _post_, tal y como tenemos en el resto del sitio.

Comment: [esta publicación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4468/11272) responde tu pregunta. Cambió el texto, y ya hay una traducción (enviada hace 4 horas). Lo único que falta es que un dev haga un build de la red de Stack Exchange

Comment: @Pikoh no olvides de poner el signo de apertura de interrogación en la traducción. Saludos.

Comment: Asi lo he hecho, puedes comprobarlo en https://traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Does%20this%20answer

Comment: @fedorqui la única que he encontrado estaba sin traducir, y lo he hecho. Es [esta](https://traducir.win/string/15141)

Comment: @Pikoh muchísimas gracias!! Qué raro que apareciera ya traducida. En cualquier caso, qué bueno que estés al quite :)

Comment: @fedorqui si, es extraño. Estaba ahora preguntando a g3rv4 a ver si nos daba una explicación.

Comment: [misterio develado](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52861276#52861276) (digo, para cerrar el círculo de la vida)