# Literal incorrecto - "Uctualiza" en lugar de "Actualiza"

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones

Más que una pregunta es un reporte de error. He visto que este literal es incorrecto:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Trasncripción:

> **Cerrada.** Esta pregunta es **off-topic**. No se ***estan*** aceptando respuestas.
>
> ¿Quieres mejorar esta pregunta? **Uctualiza la pregunta** para que sea **on-topic** ***for*** StackOverflow en español.
>
> Cerrada hace 27 min.

---

Debería poner **Actualiza** la pregunta para que sea on-topic **en** Stack Overflow en español".

Y ya que estamos: No se **están** aceptando respuestas.

Siento no poder corregirlo, pero es que no tengo acceso a [traducir.win](https://traducir.win) como se menciona en este hilo: [¿Quieres ayudar a traducir las cadenas del sitio? Este es el proceso](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3166/quieres-ayudar-a-traducir-las-cadenas-del-sitio-este-es-el-proceso)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por qué aparece <X> en inglés? ¿Estamos perdiendo traducciones?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4468/por-qu%c3%a9-aparece-x-en-ingl%c3%a9s-estamos-perdiendo-traducciones)

Comment: Se puede sugerir una mejor traducción en [traducir.win](https://traducir.win/string/15070)

Comment: Si vas a https://traducir.win/, hacés click arriba a la derecha donde dice "Log In!", ahí te tendría que ofrecer loguearte con tu cuenta de SOes (no hace falta más que eso para proponer una traducción). Una vez adentro, puedes visitar https://traducir.win/string/15070 para sugerir una traducción.

Comment: Acabo de sugerir una traducción para esa cadena. Podéis revisarla y si no os parece correcta, sugerir otra traducción.

Comment: Tambien he traducido la de _No se están aceptando respuestas._ Por cierto, no se si se ha hablado en algun momento de la traducción mas correcta para _on-topic_ y _off-topic_

Comment: @g3rv4 Me gustaría poder traducirlo, pero como he puesto en el enunciado del report no tengo acceso a traducir.win porque estoy detrás de un proxy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Como podéis ver en la captura siguiente, ya se muestra correctamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como decía en mi comentario, no se si se ha hablado en algún momento de la traducción mas correcta para *on-topic* y *off-topic*, pero creo que sería necesario hacerlo. Para *on-topic*, yo lo he traducido por *encaje en la temática*, pero *off-topic* lo he dejado en inglés.

Comment: Gracias por tomarte las molestias Pikoh

Comment: De nada @ordago. Poco se podría hacer sin vuestros reportes ;)

Comment: @Pikoh en Spanish.SE lo debatimos en su momento: [“off topic” en castellano](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/13198/1674) y las opciones que tuvieron mejor acogida fueron _fuera de ámbito_, _fuera de contexto_ y _fuera de tema_. A mí me gusta más la primera.

Comment: @fedorqui muchas gracias. _Fuera del ámbito del sitio_  me parece lo mas adecuado tambien.

Comment: Me llama la atención el contraste invertido.