# ¿Por que aparece texto en inglés en donde antes era español?

Tags: bug

Supongo que este caso se debe reportar acá...

Resulta que hoy me he dado cuenta que al `seguir` una publicación, el texto de `seguido` o `siguiendo` ya no aparece, en su efecto, aparece `following`.
He consultado con gente en el chat, y a ellos no le ocurre esto.

Por qué está ocurriendo esto ???

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por qué aparece <X> en inglés? ¿Estamos perdiendo traducciones?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4468/por-qu%c3%a9-aparece-x-en-ingl%c3%a9s-estamos-perdiendo-traducciones)

Comment: @g3rv4 entonces por que solo me pasa a mi y a nadie del chat ???

Comment: El texto en inglés era "Following" y se reemplazó por "$~post$Following", para dar contexto sobre lo que se está siguiendo es un post. En español, no nos hace una diferencia, pero en Ruso es distinto cuando se refiere a un post o a una persona

Comment: Sólo lo ven quienes siguen una publicación (podés [ver acá](https://gervas.io/following.gif) como lo veo yo). Esto se cambió ayer, y se hizo efectivo hoy cuando hicimos un build. Leé el post al que linkeé en mi primer comentario.

Comment: En principio ya está traducido. Tras el proximo build debería aparecer en español

Comment: listop! :) ya quedó subido

Comment: @g3rv4 es normal que partes de esa ayuda esten en ingles? https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @JuanRivera esto es un artículo de ayuda... y yo lo veo en español, no?

Comment: @g3rv4 mm que raro a mi me aparece en "Tablas: Our support for tables is..." asi como otros datos. Formulo una pregunta para mostarte? O por el chat stackoverflow-es ya que no creo que solo me pase a mi nomas

Comment: @JuanRivera tenes toda la razón :) lo miro el Lunes

Comment: @g3rv4 Ya me asustaba..ok :)

Comment: @JuanRivera las cadenas que están en inglés hay que traducirlas en traducir.win. Por ejemplo, [esta](https://es.traducir.win/strings/16327)